# Google API V3: How to remove overlay using Custom Overlay's onRemove() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-maps-api-3, svg

I need help on how to properly use `onRemove()` method of Google Maps API v3's Custom Overlay. I have a marker on Google Map that, when clicked, will display a d3 doughnut chart that will display certain text on hover. The chart is displayed on top of Custom Overlay. The chart should be remove (ie remove the overlay) when the marker is clicked again.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk73whr5/4/).

The remove overlay function somehow works but it still returns the error "TypeError: this.remove is not a function" which after some googling resulted from the absence of `onRemove()` method.

So I've tried adding `onRemove` method:

```
overlay.onRemove = function(){
    d3.selectAll(".donut").remove();
}
```

which didn't work. I also tried:

```
overlay.onRemove = function(){
    layer.parentNode.removeChild(layer);
}
```

and this also didn't work.

So my question is, how exactly do I use the `onRemove()` method? Or should I ignore the *TypeError* error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `else` conditional here:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  if (overlay) {
    removeDonut();
  } else { //<-- no else and showDonut was being called again after remove
    showDonut(map, marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
  }
});
```

The error was the reason it was working, it was interrupting execution.

Further, I would code it as:

```
overlay.onRemove = function(){
  this.layer.remove();
}

...

overlay.onAdd = function() {
   // keep reference to layer to remove
   this.layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget).append("div")
...
```

---

Full code:

```js
var overlay;
var layer;
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850)

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: myLatLng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  if (overlay) {
    removeDonut();
  } else {
   showDonut(map, marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
  }
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function showDonut(map, latitude, longitude) {

  var width = 1300,
    height = 1300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    fullAngle = 2 * Math.PI, // <-A
    color = d3.scale.category20();

  var endAngle = fullAngle;
  var innerRadius = 50;
  var totalNode = 5;
  var names = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"];
  var data = [];
  var startPoint = 0;
  //endAngle = fullAngle/totalNode;
  for (i = 1; i <= totalNode; i++) {
    data.push({
      value: fullAngle / totalNode,
    });
  }

  overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  
  overlay.onRemove = function(){
   this.layer.remove();
  }
  
  // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
  overlay.onAdd = function() {
    this.layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget).append("div")
      .attr("class", "donut");
    // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
    // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
    overlay.draw = function() {

      var projection = this.getProjection(),
        padding = 0;

      d = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);

      xpos = d.x;
      ypos = d.y - 25; //need to adjust based on marker height

      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(100)
        .innerRadius(50);

      var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        });

      var svg = d3.select(".donut").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + xpos + "," + ypos + ")");

      var arcs = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

      arcs.append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) {
          return "pie-" + i;
        })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        })
        .style("opacity", "0.7")
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
          //change pie opacity
          d3.select("#" + this.id)
            .style("opacity", "1")
            .style("cursor", "pointer")

          //div for text
          svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "labelBox")
            .attr("x", -100)
            .attr("y", 115)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", 50)
            .style("fill", 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)')

          //display text
          svg.append("text")
            .attr("dy", 150)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("background-color", "white")
            .style("font-size", 'xx-large')
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return "black";
            })
            .text(names[i])
        })
        //change opacity to normal and remove text
        .on("mouseout", function() {
          //svg.select("#"+this.id).style("fill", color(i))
          svg.select("#" + this.id).style("opacity", "0.7")
          svg.select(".label").remove()
          svg.select(".labelBox").remove()
        })
        //open infoWindow
        .on("click", function(d, i) {
          //svg.select(".label").text("Clicked!!")
          alert(names[i])
        });
    };

  };
  // Bind our overlay to the map…
  overlay.setMap(map);
}

function removeDonut() { 
  overlay.setMap(null);
  overlay = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<body style='background-color:#0e0e0e'>
  <div id='googleMap' style="position:absolute;left:0;top:5%;width:100%; height:90%;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think leaving `else` was the problem. Not keeping the layer reference was the problem. So adding `this.layer = ...` and using `this.layer.remove();` to remove solve the problem. Thanks!